# Saving an sklearn.svm.SVR model as JSON instead of pickling

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have a trained SVR model which needs to be saved in a ***JSON*** format instead of pickling.

The idea behind JSONifying the trained model is to simply capture the state of the weights and other 'fitted' attributes. Then, I can set these attributes later to make predictions. Here is an implementation of it I did:

```py
    # assume SVR has been trained
    regressor = SVR()
    regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

    # saving the regressor params in a JSON file for later retrieval
    with open(f'saved_regressor_params.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        json.dump(regressor.get_params(), outfile)

    # finding the fitted attributes of SVR()
    # if an attribute is trailed by '_', it's a fitted attribute
    attrs = [i for i in dir(regressor) if i.endswith('_') and not i.endswith('__')]
    remove_list = ['coef_', '_repr_html_', '_repr_mimebundle_'] # unnecessary attributes
    
    for attr in remove_list:
        if attr in attrs:
            attrs.remove(attr)


    # deserialize NumPy arrays and save trained attribute values into JSON file
    attr_dict = {i: getattr(regressor, i) for i in attrs}

    for k in attr_dict:
        if isinstance(attr_dict[k], np.ndarray):
            attr_dict[k] = attr_dict[k].tolist()

    # dump JSON for prediction
    with open(f'saved_regressor_{index}.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:    
        json.dump(attr_dict, 
                    outfile, 
                    separators=(',', ':'), 
                    sort_keys=True, 
                    indent=4)
```

This would create two separate `json` files. One file called `saved_regressor_params.json` which saves certain required parameters for SVR and another is called `saved_regressor.json` which stores attributes and their trained values as objects. Example (saved_regressor.json):

```json
{
    "_dual_coef_":[
        [
            -1.0,
            -1.0,
            -1.0,
        ]
    ],
    "_intercept_":[
        1.323423423
    ],
         ...
         ...

    "_n_support_":[
        3
    ]
}
```

Later, I can create a new SVR() model and simply set these parameters and attributes into it by calling them from the existing JSON files we just created. Then, call in the `predict()` method to predict. Like so (in a new file):

```py
predict_svr = SVR()

#load the json from the files
obj_text = codecs.open('saved_regressor_params.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
params = json.loads(obj_text)

obj_text = codecs.open('saved_regressor.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
attributes = json.loads(obj_text)

#setting params
predict_svr.set_params(**params)

# setting attributes
for k in attributes:
        if isinstance(attributes[k], list):
            setattr(predict_svr, k, np.array(attributes[k]))
        else:
            setattr(predict_svr, k, attributes[k])
        
predict_svr.predict(...)
```

However, during this process, a particular attribute called: `n_support_` cannot be set due to some reason. And even if I ignore `n_support_` attribute, it creates additional errors. (Is my logic wrong or am I missing something here?)

Therefore, I am looking for different ways or ingenious methods to save an SVR model into JSON.

I have tried the existing third party helper libraries like: `sklearn_json`. These libraries tend to export perfectly for linear models but not for support vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Making a reproducible example missing in the OP, based on the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) (version 1.1.2)

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
n_samples, n_features = 10, 5
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
y = rng.randn(n_samples)
X = rng.randn(n_samples, n_features)
regressor = SVR(C=1.0, epsilon=0.2)
regressor.fit(X, y)
```

Then a sketch of the a JSON serialization/deserialization

```py
import json
# serialize
serialized = json.dumps({
    k: v.tolist() if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v 
    for k, v in regressor.__dict__.items()
})

# deserialize
regressor2 = SVR()
regressor2.__dict__ = {
     k: np.asarray(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v 
     for k, v in json.loads(serialized).items()
}

# test
assert np.all(regressor.predict(X) == regressor2.predict(X))
```

### EDIT: Serialization preserving data type

A not so elegant solution to address the first issue mentioned in a comment is to save the data type together with the data.

```py
import json
# serialize


serialized = json.dumps({
    k: [v.tolist(), 'np.ndarray', str(v.dtype)] if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v 
    for k, v in regressor.__dict__.items()
})

# deserialize
regressor2 = SVR()
regressor2.__dict__ = {
     k: np.asarray(v[0], dtype=v[2]) if isinstance(v, list) and v[1] == 'np.ndarray' else v 
     for k, v in json.loads(serialized).items()
}

# test
assert np.all(regressor.predict(X) == regressor2.predict(X))
```

Comment: This works well while setting the attributes. Once I call in the `predict()` method, it throws me this error: `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int32_t' but got 'long'`.

Comment: Well, you may have to handle multiple corner cases like this. That's why it is called custom code.